# list filter in display text change in extjs

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

my grid in display data 1-admin and 2 - standard
apply list filter on grid it display 1 and 2
i need to display "admin" and "standard"

check image:[image]

code :

```
{     text: 'UserType', dataIndex: 'UserTypeId', groupable: true,
                        filter: {
                            type: 'list', active: true
                        },
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            if (value == 1) {
                                return "Admin";
                            }
                            else
                                return "Standard";
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              {    
                text: 'UserType', dataIndex: 'UserTypeId', groupable: true,
                    filter: {
                       type: 'list', active: true,
                       options: [1,'Admin', 2,'Standard']
                    },
                    renderer: function (value) {
                        if (value == 1) {
                            return "Admin";
                        }
                        else
                            return "Standard";
                    }
                },
```

it's working

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please add the following config to your filter to make it show the filters as required

```
        {    
            text: 'UserType', dataIndex: 'UserTypeId', groupable: true,
                        filter: {
                           type: 'list', active: true,
                           options: ['Standard', 'Admin']
                        },
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            if (value == 1) {
                                return "Admin";
                            }
                            else
                                return "Standard";
                        }
                    },
```

Check [here in docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter-cfg-options) for further info.HOPE IT HELPS YOU.